# conditionally display radio buttons based on user's select box choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is some sample code - trying to get the radio buttons to display only when the user picks a specific option from the select box.  See the two comments in the script tags specifying the requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    ul {list-style-type: none;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //what jQuery code is needed here so that the following occurs?
        //1. the label for the radio buttons and the radio buttons themselves only appears when the user picks Formula Type 3 from the select box
        //2. when the radio buttons and label are not displayed, the space they were in remains but it just looks empty (the word "placeholder", in the third li tag, does NOT move up underneath the select box)
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="FormulaType">Formula Type</label>
            <select name="FormulaType" id="FormulaType">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Type1">Type1</option>
                <option value="Type2">Type2</option>
                <option value="Type3">Type3</option>
                <option value="Type4">Type4</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="OutputFat">Output Fat Is</label>
            <input type="radio" name="OutputFat" value="low">lowest
            <input type="radio" name="OutputFat" value="high">highest       
            </radio>
        </li>
        <li>
            placeholder
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#FormulaType').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('li').next().css('visibility', $this.val() == 'Type3'? 'visible' : 'hidden')
        //if don't want to preserve the space
        //$this.closest('li').next().toggle($(this).val() == 'Type3')
    }).triggerHandler('change')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xhX5/)

Comment: Second requirement is not met, OP is looking to toggle CSS visibility to preserve empty space

Comment: @koala_dev I read it the other way... use [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) in that case

Comment: yeah it's kind of ambiguous, let's see if the OP clarifies

Comment: Yes - the use of visibility meets the second requirement.  This code works!  However, I don't understand how it knows to pick the second li tag as the one to make invisible.  How would the code change if the requirement had been to make the li that holds the word "placeholder" invisible when formula type Type3 is picked?

Comment: @knot22 here what I did find the `next li` of the `li` with the `select` field

Comment: @knot22 do you want to hide the `li` with text `placeholder` or the `li` with `radio` buttons

Comment: Originally, I wanted to hide the radio buttons.  I asked about hiding the li that holds the word "placeholder" to see what that code would look like to hopefully get an understanding of how to pick a different element to hide should that requirement arise in another project in the future.

Comment: @knot22 in that case you can use `:contains`, try `$this.closest('li').siblings(':contains("placeholder")')`